# Replacing map entries using a macro

Tags: elixir

I would appreciate some help in understanding whats going on here and as a secondary thought if its a correct/non-smelly way to do things.

I have two Modules in their own files:

```
defmodule ModuleA do
   def mapA do
    %{a: 1, 
      b: 2,
      c: 3,
      d: 4
     }
   end
   def mapA_lookup(id) when is_atom(i) do
    Dict.get(mapA, id)
   end
end
```

and

```
defmodule ModuleB do
   import ModuleA

   defmacro a_value_from_MapA do
     quote do ModuleA.mapA_lookup(:a) end
   end

   def mapB do
    %{e: a_value_from_MapA, #needs to have same value as :a
      f: 5,
      g: 6
     }
    end
  def mapB_lookup(id) when is_atom(id) do
    Dict.get(mapB, id)
  end
end
```

Now when I use

```
mapB_lookup(:e)
```

I get the expected value...good for me  :-).

This doesnt work if I "plug in"

```
ModuleA.mapA_lookup(:a)
```

directly in the definition of MapB (The BEAM goes mental and my ExUnit tests time out).

What I'm trying to do is be quite explicit where the values come from in MapB, since in my code, in real life, I'm using the maps to define ASN1 types (MapA) and derived types (MapB).

So the question(s) is/are:

Why and how does the macro definition work? (I know we are fiddling around with the AST but how in this context makes my brain ache)

Is there a better pattern to acheive my goal?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: By the way, I didn't list it in my answer but I just tried that with Elixir 1.1.0 and Erlang 18.1.  I don't believe the version is going to make a big difference but if you're on an older version of Elixir, you may want to add that to your question.

Comment: Yes good idea. Running 1.05 and erlang 18.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy your literal code?  Because I think this is an error:

```
def mapA_lookup(id) when is_atom(i) do
    Dict.get(mapA, id)
   end
```

I think you meant:

```
   def mapA_lookup(id) when is_atom(id) do
    Dict.get(mapA, id)
   end
```

Note the is_atom guard clause.

Of course if you copied the code wrong, then never mind.

By the way, I seriously doubt you need a macro to do this.  If I get a chance I'll see if I can hack together some demo code and append it to this answer.

---

EDIT:

Yes as a matter of fact I think your code is almost right but you definitely don't need a macro.  This worked for me:

```
defmodule ModuleA do
   def mapA do
    %{a: 1, 
      b: 2,
      c: 3,
      d: 4
     }
   end
   def mapA_lookup(id) when is_atom(id) do
    Dict.get(mapA, id)
   end
end

defmodule ModuleB do
   import ModuleA

   def mapB do
    %{e: mapA_lookup(:a), #needs to have same value as :a
      f: 5,
      g: 6
     }
    end
  def mapB_lookup(id) when is_atom(id) do
    Dict.get(mapB, id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your version of the code( it was my initial solution) but as I said when I run that code at least from unit tests they time out and the beam seems pretty busy in a similar manner to when recursion goes wrong.

Comment: Then I'd guess it's some issue with the unit tests.  The code above works just fine. Maybe you want to add some detail about the unit tests or create a separate question.